# What is the meaning of the English word “ravished” in this sentence, violated or transfixed?

Tags: vocabulario, traducción

I’m trying to figure out the best word in Spanish to translate the English
word *ravished* as it’s used in the following context:

> There, before my **ravished** eye, a Cube, moving in some altogether
> new direction, but strictly according to Analogy, so as to make every
> particle of his interior pass through a new kind of Space with a wake
> of its own — shall create a still more perfect perfection than himself,
> with sixteen terminal Extra-solid angles, and Eight solid Cubes for
> his Perimeter.
>
> ―*Flatland: A Romance Of Many Dimensions* by Edwin Abbot. Page 89, first paragraph.

Generally it is not difficult to determine using [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/es/ravished) or [Google
Translator](https://translate.google.com.mx/?sl=auto&tl=es&text=ravished&op=translate), but this time this particular word throws up meanings that
are almost opposite of each other, it could mean “raped” — *violado, ultrajado*
— or “spellbound” — *embelesado, extasiado*. Which sense fits better in this
sentence?

I was about to translate it to:

> Allí, ante mi ojo arrebatado, un Cubo, ...

But in Spanish this sounds weird, so I need a second point of view. How
can I translate this English sentence into Spanish that sounds natural
while keeping the original author’s meaning intact?

Comment: It's odd, but more like *horrorizado* -- horrified or shocked. No, not raped, more like overcome with shock.

Comment: Se me ocurre que habrá unas cuantas posibilidades aquí, pero te aseguro que recibirías mejores respuestas a tu pregunta a nuestro sitio hermana, [spanish.se]. Dame un momento para arreglar todo eso.

Comment: I see, *ojo horrorizado*  sounds weird also, but this bring me to another one: *ojo conmocionado* and I think this sounds good according to the situation.

Comment: @tchrist De acuerdo. De cualquier manera el comentario de Yosef Baskin ha sido de mucha ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: @YosefBaskin You really nail it. I never thought that way, but henceforth I'll consider that criterion when choosing a particular word in a translation.

Comment: Yes, start with the meaning of transfixed, fascinated, mesmerized, hypnotized, locked. Then use a similar startling word en Espanol. A translation is an interpretation, not a twin, and she can be either faithful or beautiful. I like beautiful, because that is what your reader will read. Can you imagine the reader who says "This Spanish is ugly, but it's so true to the original"? No.

Comment: Don't use Google or that deep thing. They are all misleading unless you already know the terms.  Aqui en la frase, se trata de un placer en relación a la vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using real dictionaries like the Larousse English<>Spanish ones. This one is free and online. There are others, too.
It says, for ravish: embelesado.

[Larousse Spanish <>English](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-espagnol/ravish/30440)
Here the man *seems to be taking pleasure in the situation.*

1. First, determine what the English means. Only the archaic meaning is "raped" and here, that would make little sense.

Merriam Webster:

Definition of ravish
transitive verb

1a: to seize and take away by violence   [not relevant]
b: **to overcome with emotion (such as joy or delight)** [relevant for an eye]
ravished by the scenic beauty
c: RAPE entry 1 sense 1

2. It is very likely here to mean: embelezado (RAE: arrebetar o cautivar los sentidos) or simply encantar.

[ravish in Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravish?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)

When translating literature, never just use a bilingual dictionary. Look up the word in a source language monolingual dictionary first.

Comment: "Only the archaic meaning is "raped"" The use of "ravished" to mean "raped" isn't archaic at all; it's pretty commonly used in erotic fiction, for instance, where it'd often have a connotation like "raped/physically forced to have sex, but she enjoyed it because she secretly wanted it".

Comment: @nick012000 "He ravished her", does not mean she wanted it.  I doubt, even in erotic fiction, that a woman would say that. That might be an imputation by an author. In any case, it is irrelevant here.

Comment: "Bodice-ripper" stories about sexy men ravishing the novel's heroine are the most popular genre of erotic fiction, bar none. 50 Shades of Gray was a best-seller for a reason. Obviously, real rape is bad, but pretend fantasy rape is different.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_fantasy ravishment is not literal rape anymore.

Comment: I suppose that depends on how you define "literal rape", but sure.

Comment: If I were to read a passage describing Vikings raiding a coastal village and _ravishing_ the local women, I would immediately understand that they were violently forced, raped. This isn't remotely archaic and would be unremarkable in a contemporary historical novel or an actual history book.

Comment: @terdon Whatever. It could mean they were carried off violently. With the raping coming later.

Comment: @Lambie It could also mean that they had roses plaited into their hair. However, it doesn't, because that isn't what the word means. And since no dictionary I can see considers it "archaic", you have offered no reference to back your claim and the claim is trivially proven wrong by a cursory check on any corpus, it might make sense to remove the claim instead of arguing. But, as you so politely put it, "whatever".

Comment: @terdon It is getting slightly tiresome to be told that ravished means raped. In today's world, it simply is not used as a euphemism for rape or to mean rape in **contemporary writing**.  Of course, in the 18th century it could have used like that, say, in Fanny Hill and similar books. Now, can you find it in historical fiction? Probably. Sure. But please, dig through the corpora. I can't be bothered.

Comment: I know you can't since if you had done so (it took me less than five minutes on Google Books) you wouldn't be trying to convince us of something that is clearly wrong. But hey, you do you.

Comment: Googling in Google books is one thing; ploughing through the uses is another.

Comment: See what I mean? The results are clear: Only one title is remotely relevant. Crime and Ravishment (A literary usage); and everything else goes back pretty far. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ravishment%22&hl=en-US&biw=1336&bih=644&tbm=bks&ei=WDrjYOqQLoq-tAa-0ajIDQ&oq=%22ravishment%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1.4178.9900.0.10252.24.19.5.0.0.0.217.1608.13j5j1.19.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.16.1075...0j0i10k1j0i13k1j0i13i10k1.0.DKT04rAgjWc

Answer (score 6):

There are probably many translations which would fit the meaning here which is that the author's eye had been delighted by the sight.

I would suggest [*cautivado*](https://dle.rae.es/cautivar?m=form) from *cautivar* for which the third definition in the entry linked to above is

> 3. tr. Ejercer irresistible influencia en el ánimo de alguien por medio de atractivo físico o moral.

Comment: se trata de un ojo, una mirada....no me gusta mucha ojo cautivado.....

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the English word *ravish* in this context is something like [*enrapture*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enrapture) — to fill with delight. I can't say if the Google translation to *extasiar* is accurate, but it might provide a starting point.

Comment: Perhaps "embelesado".

Answer (score 2):

It’s an old book, so an obvious trick is to check existing translations:

> Allí, ante mi ojo deslumbrado, un cubo, moviéndose en una dirección completamente nueva, pero rigurosamente de acuerdo con la analogía, de manera que haga que cada partícula de su interior pase a través de un nuevo género de espacio, con una estela propia, creará una perfección aún más perfecta que él mismo, con dieciséis ángulos extrasólidos terminales, y ocho cubos sólidos por perímetro.

[Version](http://mimosa.pntic.mec.es/jgomez53/docencia/abbott-planilandia.pdf) by José Manuel Álvarez Flórez, Ed. Torre de Viento.

Comment: Well, deslumbrado, maybe.

Comment: There are many good options in the answers, but Merriam Webster's example "*ravished by the scenic beauty*", commented elsewhere, corresponds very well to the common phrase "*deslumbrado por la belleza del paisaje*". And nothing can be more *deslumbrado* than an eye.